# Python, Run module and analyse results in console

Tags: python, pydev

I have a python module that loads a large file.  It then does some analysis on the file.

After the module has finished running, I would like to be able to analyse the results (well, the variables that it created) in the Console.

e.g.  The module is

```
df=pd.read_csv(large_file)
```

after running the module I would like to analyse df in a console

```
print(len(df['HELLO']))
```

I am currently using Pydev in Eclipse.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Multiples solutions are available:

- Outside of PyDev/Eclipse, you could insert `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` at the end of your program (where the scope of your needed variables is still valid). This would start you a prompt interpreter that would take in commands that would allow you exactly what you requested.
- You can put a breakpoint in PyDev. This will stop the execution of your program and change the view to the debug perspective. In the watch panel, you can request the values of the variables you want as well as their content's values.
- You could use the `json`, `pickle` or similar module to dump your object into a file that could be analysed later on. Something along the lines of `import pickle; pickle.dump( myVariable, open( "myFile.pkl", "wb" ) )`. After your program ran, you could launch an interpreter and execute `import pickle; myVar = pickle.load( open( "myFile.pkl", "rb" ) )`. This will give you myVar in your interpreter.